# How might I pass a variable's value from a Django template into client-side JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, variables, django-templates

How can I pass a variable value from a template using JavaScript without using a form (GET OR POST)?

Comment: You need to provide more details. Pass a variable from the template to... where? Send information back to the server without a GET or POST? What are you really trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send this value from JavaScript via Xml Http Request without using form - see how AJAX works.
See for example [POST request](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.post) with jQuery JS library.

The `uri` parameter is URI of your Django view, `data` - JS object that you send to server and finally `callback` - JS function to process server response.